# Como puedo realizar la estructura json en php trayendo datos con un while

Tags: php, json

por favor necesito ayuda para armar la siguiente estructura en php siendo la información obtenida de un while .

```
"ite":{
                    "items1":
                        [
                           {
                              "item":"cabecera",
                               "emisor_id":1,
                           },
                           {
                               "item":"detalle",
                               "emisor_id":1,
                           }
                         ],
                      "items2":
                         [
                         ],
              
        }
```

Porfa si alguien me puede ayudar en php tengo el siguiente codigo

```
 $array2 = array();
                      $array2["ite"] = array();
                      $array = array();
                      $array["item"] = array()

;
              While() {
              
              
              $item = array(
                              'item'='cabecera',
                           );
              
              $it = 'item';
              
                          array_push($array[$it],$item);
            while (){
               $item2 =array(
                               'item'='detalle',
                            );
              
               array_push($array['item'],$item2);
            }
          }
```

y al final que le ingreso en item cabecera le ingreso en ite array

```
array_push($array2['ite'],$array);
```

pero el json se arma asi

```
 {
                 "ite":[
                    {
                       "item":"cabecera",
                     }
                     {
                      "item":"detalle",
                      }
                    ]
              }
```

y no es lo que necesito por favor si me pueden dar una mano o si puedo formarla de otra manera

Comment: Dudo que estés generando el arreglo manualmente, por favor edita la pregunta para especificar si estás obteniendo los datos desde base de datos u otra fuente y cómo estas intentando armar la estructura. Aunque no le veo mucho sentido a ese "contador" _items1, items2, ..._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma de declarar un `array` es por medio del operador `=>`

**PHP**

```
$estructura = array(
    'ite' => array(
        'items1' => array(
            array('item' => 'cabecera','emisor_id' => 1), 
            array('item' => 'detalle','emisor_id' => 1)
        ),
        'items2' => array()
    )
);

echo json_encode($estructura);
```

**SALIDA**

```
{"ite":{"items1":[{"item":"cabecera","emisor_id":1},{"item":"detalle","emisor_id":1}],"items2":[]}}
```

Tan solo es ir teniendo claro la estructura de niveles que tiene el **array multidimensional**. De esta manera puedes construir la estructura que necesitas sin necesidad de ir construyendo cada elemento por separado para después hacerle **push**

Comment: hola gracias por tu respuesta Y como este lo utilizaría con datos que vienen de un while por ejemplo este emisor_id es valor diferente cada vez que se repite y tambien con un detalle diferente ?

Answer (score 0):

Te puede servir `json_decode()` o puedes crear directamente la estructura.

```
$json='{
   "ite":{
      "items1":[
         {
            "item":"cabecera",
            "emisor_id":1
         },
         {
            "item":"detalle",
            "emisor_id":1
         }
      ],
      "items2":[

      ]
   }
}';

$array=json_decode($json,true);
var_dump($array);

//OTRA FORMA

$array2=[
   "ite"=>[
      "items1"=>[
         0=>[
            "item"=>"cabecera",
            "emisor_id"=>1
         ],
         1=>[
            "item"=>"detalle",
            "emisor_id"=>1
         ]
      ],
      "items2"=>[

      ]
   ]
];
    
var_dump($array2);
```

Referencias:

https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php

https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php